# bitcoin.Psbt doesn't auto-display its method/properties in Visual Studio Code

Tags: bitcoinjs, bip174-psbt

When instantiating a new Psbt in my Visual Studio Code like below:

```
  const psbt = new bitcoin.Psbt()
```

The variable `psbt` doesn't auto display any of its methods/properties after I add the `.` right after it. Why is this?

Comment: Can you also include the line where you import/require bitcoinjs?

Comment: `import * as bitcoin from "../../../../bitcoinjs-lib"`

It's importing to the browser as I am using it in a React app

Comment: That's a strange way to be importing a library. Why don't you install it using a package manager (npm/yarn)? It comes with type definitions which you likely haven't included in your way of importing it.